# Current time in UTC in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want current time in UTC format.I am using this code

```
 NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"myDate = %@",myDate);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
NSLog(@"Time zone = %@",timeZone);
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"localDateString = %@",localDateString);
```

But the timezone showing is GMT.

the loged result is

```
  myDate = 2014-05-30 05:37:39 +0000
  Time zone = GMT (GMT) offset 0
  localDateString = 20140530053739
```

Any one know why this happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explain how the timezone is being shown. Your date format doesn't show the timezone.

Comment: @rmaddy  while NSLog(@"%@",timeZone); it shows the result as   

 GMT (GMT) offset 0

Comment: Does `localDateString` show the proper value in UTC? That's what matters. Update your question with the log output of `myDate`, `timeZone`, and `localDateString`.

Comment: UTC is the same as GMT

Comment: @rmaddy while logging the result is
myDate = 2014-05-30 05:37:39 +0000
Time zone = GMT (GMT) offset 0
localDateString = 20140530053739

Comment: Update your question with that info.

Comment: What about this guys. http://www.diffen.com/difference/GMT_vs_UTC